# How can I close lean modal popup after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, so i am using a lean modal script, and i want after it processes my code to automaticaly close after 3 seconds. The lean modal script looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                top: 100,
                overlay: 0.5,
                closeButton: null
            };
            var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                $(this).click(function(e) {
                    var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");
                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function() {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    $(o.closeButton).click(function() {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();
                    $("#lean_overlay").css({
                        "display": "block",
                        opacity: 0
                    });
                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);
                    $(modal_id).css({
                        "display": "block",
                        "position": "fixed",
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "z-index": 11000,
                        "left": 50 + "%",
                        "margin-left": -(modal_width / 2) + "px",
                        "top": o.top + "px"
                    });
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
                    e.preventDefault()
                })
            });

            function close_modal(modal_id) {
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

The modal windows is opened on the main index page, but another php script processes a form within this modal windows. What javascript code do i need in my processing page to close this? Thanks in advance.

tried using this to close it but will close only the low opacity thing surrounding the popup container:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })
                $(".popupContainer").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })
                $(".popupBody").fadeOut(200);
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })


            }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can trigger click on overlay which closes the modal or trigger click on close button if any.
try this.

```
$("#lean_overlay").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the job. Didnt know you can trigger click.